# PowerShell to check for count of each row using bat file

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file

How can I count for each row in a .csv file and delete the row if it contains count=14?

ex: I have a abc.csv file, each column in A1 has some text. I would need to check for length of each Column in a file

```
(len(a)!=10)
```

then delete the row.
Data as below:

```
abcxyz.jpg 
pqrxyzs.jpg
```

Here length is 11 so it has to get deleted.

Comment: I tried with Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv | Measure-Object

Comment: But here its checking for a all the row, I need to check of each row

Comment: `Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv | foreach {Measure-Object}` ?

Comment: `cat 'C:\path\to\your.file' | ? { $_.Length -eq 10 }`?

Comment: @Echo off
Set _File=photo.csv
Set /a _Lines=0
For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< %_File%') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines

pause

Comment: Hi I have tried , but its printing  the all the files row count

Comment: What does the `count=14` represent? Number of characters in the row? And what is the A1 column?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(import-csv "C:\temp\missing.csv" | where { $_.name.Length -le 10}) | export-csv "C:\temp\missing.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```